# Why pseudo code and tables don't show in pdf version?

Tags: tables, pseudocode, mwe

I am writing a research paper using an official template. When I run .tex file, it shows all the text and images, but it does not show tables and pseudo code (Even packages are included).

Please have a look https://mc03.manuscriptcentral.com/societyimages/jcst/JCST-Template-%20SubmitLatex202111.zip

Thank You so much

Comment: Welcome. // I suggest preparing and posting a MWE. To do so, start with the template and remove most of it, while keeping e.g. a figure and a pseudo code, which shows your problem. Next Edit your question and add this MWE.

Comment: This is my first time using latex, can you tell me what is MWE

Comment: @YasirGlani - Please see (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that)

Comment: Just follow the steps I lined out. However, I assume you can edit a .tex file and compile it one way or the other: from a GUI or from the command-line/terminal. If you can't please serach for a beginners intro or tutorial, e.g. here https://latex-tutorial.com/tutorials/ , on YouTube etc.